# how to pick path with MemoryStream

Tags: c#, asp.net, memorystream

I have the following code:

```
using (Stream responseStream = reply.GetResponseStream())
{
    //Do not close the stream, this creates an error when saving a JPEG file
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead;
    do
    {
        bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    } while (bytesRead != 0);
}
```

When I used this in a console application, the file saved automatically to bin folder. Now I use it in a web application - and it is not saved at all.
How can I give a `MemoryStream` a specific path so it will saved there, for example: `"c:\\file.jpg"`?

Comment: Have a look at `FileStream`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The code you've provided wouldn't have saved anything to disk in a console app. It's unclear what you're trying to do - if you're writing to a *response* stream, you're just writing to the HTTP response... what does that have to do with writing to a file? Please clarify the question.

Comment: A MemoryStream doesn't have a path as it is in memory only. Nor do I see you saving anything to disk in the code you posted.

Comment: i get data from other URL and want to save it to file in the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming `reply` is an instance of `HttpWebResponse` (via `HttpWebRequest`).

Anyway, .NET 4 comes with `Stream.CopyTo` which simplifies the process of copying from one stream to another without you needing to manually do it yourself with your own buffer.

Like so:

```
using( Stream responseStream = reply.GetResponseStream() )
using( Stream fileStream = new FileStream( @"C:\whatever\foo.bin", FileMode.CreateNew ) ) {
    responseStream.CopyTo( fileStream );
}
```

That's it.